# TestFlight- How to send invitation for testing the build to individual candidates

Tags: ios, testflight

As mentioned in title, I want to send notification for testing to the individual person listed inside my internal testers.

Seems like Apple has changed the interface. For example - I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/101790/ios-beta-testing-with-testflight-tutorial) and I'm not seeing an option to select the individual candidates. This doesn't seem to work in my case.

[image: select]

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 4):

[image: new interface]

This is the new interface, you just have to add desired email addresses in Internal Testers and start testing by selecting build number.

Comment: Where shall I enter the email address? I already have 8 internal testers.

Comment: ok just start testing. You don't have to select emails separately. All emails in internal testing will be notified.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't want to send emails to all the 8 candidates, I want to send email to only 2 or 3 persons.

Comment: Ok then just add only required emails in Internal testers. Remove all others from that list.

Comment: Refresh that page and try again.